# add ID row to the query in SQL access

Tags: ms-access

HELLO EVERYBODY I HAVE A SQL CODE AND I WANT ADD NEW ROW TO IT AND I WANT THE ID ROW IS AUTONUMBER PLEASE PAY ATTENTION TO THE BELOW CODE AND I WANT JUST CREATE A ROW THAT NAME IS id and it is autonumber

```
SELECT
    Table30.code AS code,
    Table30.desc AS description,
    Table30.manufacturer AS manufacturer1,
    Table31.manufacturer AS manufacturer2,
    Table30.partdes AS partdes1,
    Table31.partdes AS partdes2,
    Table30.qty AS QuantityInTable30,
    Table31.qty AS QuantityInTable31,
    IIf(Table31.partdes IS NULL, 'Delete', 
        IIf(Table30.partdes IS NULL, 'Add', 
            IIf(Table30.qty <> Table31.qty, 'Change', 'No Change'))) AS Status
FROM 
    Table30
LEFT JOIN 
    Table31 ON Table30.partdes = Table31.partdes

UNION ALL SELECT 
    Table31.code AS code,
    Table31.desc AS description,
    Table30.manufacturer AS manufacturer1,
    Table31.manufacturer AS manufacturer2,
      Table30.partdes AS partdes1,
    Table31.partdes AS partdes2,
    Null AS QuantityInTable30,
    Table31.qty AS QuantityInTable31,
    'Add' AS Status
FROM 
    Table31
LEFT JOIN 
    Table30 ON Table31.partdes = Table30.partdes
WHERE 
    Table30.partdes IS NULL;
```